# Object not found in `geom_bar()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to map `prop` to the y-axis on my bar chart but I keep getting the "object not found" error. How do I fix my code? Thank you!

```
dput(starwars_age)
structure(list(`Age Response` = c("> 60", "18-29", "30-44", "45-60"
), n = c(193L, 180L, 207L, 240L), prop = c(0.206196581196581, 
0.192307692307692, 0.221153846153846, 0.256410256410256)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

starwars_age %>%
  mutate(`Age Response` = factor(`Age Response`, levels  = c("18-29","30-44","45-60","> 60"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Age Response`))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = prop))

Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomBar, : object 'prop' not found
```

Comment: Do you want `geom_bar(aes(y = prop), stat = 'identity')` ?

Comment: Yes, that does the job! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add `stat = 'identity'` in `geom_bar` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

starwars_age %>%
  mutate(`Age Response` = factor(`Age Response`, 
                          levels  = c("18-29","30-44","45-60","> 60"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Age Response`)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = prop), stat = 'identity')
```

[image]